# TreeTableView items disappear when scroll down and double-click last expand/collapse arrow

Tags: java, javafx

While working with a `TreeTableView` I realized that when you scroll down the table and double click the last expand/collapse arrow, all items disappear. However, when you scroll again all items reappear. Of course, this happens when you have enough items so the vertical `ScrollBar` is active.

Does anyone experience this issue before? Is this a known issue?

**Simple example:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TreeTableView<List<String>> table = new TreeTableView<>();
        table.setMaxHeight(250);

        TreeTableColumn<List<String>, String> colCity = new TreeTableColumn<>("City");
        TreeTableColumn<List<String>, String> colCountry = new TreeTableColumn<>("Country");

        colCity.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getValue().get(0)));
        colCountry.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getValue().get(1)));

        table.getColumns().setAll(colCity, colCountry);

        TreeItem<List<String>> root = new TreeItem<>(Arrays.asList("Root", ""));
        root.setExpanded(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TreeItem<List<String>> item = new TreeItem<>(List.of("London", "UK"));
            item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(List.of("New York", "US")));
            item.setExpanded(true);
            root.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        table.setRoot(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(table));

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I have tested this code on:

- Hardware/OS: MacBookPro16,1/macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- Java: 11.0.2, 14.0.1
- JavaFX: 11.0.2, 12.0.2, 13.0.2, 14.0.2.1, 15

Comment: @kleopatra, what do you mean? The one posted in the question is not a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @kleopatra OP added an example and it seems to reproduce the issue on my computer

Comment: oops .. my mistake, sry .. will check later if we have a bug like that

Comment: this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8244826 looks similar - treeTable going blank when collapsing an item off the viewport .. p4 only .. hmm. added a reference to this question in the report.

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra, I'll take a look into that bug report. P4 seems to low for this issue given how it can affect user experience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JavaFX 16 this issue is solved. However, here's a *hacky* solution for older JavaFX versions.

It works by adding a listener to the `expandedItemCountProperty()` to force the `TreeTableView` to refresh when needed:

```
table.expandedItemCountProperty().addListener(e -> {

    VirtualFlow<?> virtualFlow = (VirtualFlow<?>) table.lookup(".virtual-flow");

    if (virtualFlow != null && virtualFlow.getFirstVisibleCell() != null) {

        int firstVisibleIndex = virtualFlow.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
        int visibleCells = virtualFlow.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex() - firstVisibleIndex;

            if (firstVisibleIndex > visibleCells) {
                table.refresh();
            }
    }
});
```

Note: tested using the example in the question.